# Can a developer change the minimum payment threshold?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to change the minimum payment threshold generated by inApp purchases?

Google allows to change the minimum threshold (i.e.: 3.000€) and also to postpone the payment till 1 year.

This is very useful for starting indie studios in countries with a bad entrepreneur tax policies. Even a small invoice will force the studio to pay 600€ taxes per month to remain legal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't change the payment threshold. It'll always be either whatever is listed in the minimum payment threshold table, or $40 USD (if it's not).

Source: [App Store Connect > Reference > Minimum payment threshold](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/minimum-payment-threshold)

> Before payment can be sent to your bank, your account must meet the
> minimum payment threshold.
>
> If your bank account currency and the
> country or region where your bank is based are listed in the table
> below, you must exceed the minimum payment threshold listed. All other
> bank countries or regions and bank account currencies must exceed a
> minimum payment threshold of 40 USD.